# Infragistics UltraGrid C# winform

Tags: .net, winforms, infragistics

I would like to select multiple rows in the ultragrid WITHOUT holding the CTRL key.
Is it possible?

I have rowSelecteType = extended.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on what you want to achieve.

If you don't want to allow the users to edit cells, then you can simply set the CellClickAction to RowSelect (next to your rowselecttype)

```
yourGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect;
```

Another option is to make rowselectors visible, the user can then use those to select rows; an other advantage of this is that the user can still edit cells

```
yourGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = DefaultableBoolean.True;
```

Comment: i do have this setting alread, but i wanna be able to select mutiple row WITHOUT holding the "ctrl" key.

this only select single row.
thank you

Comment: If you have the rowselectors, you should be able to select multiple (subsequent) rows using the selectors in front of the row.  Yes, without holding the ctrl key.

Comment: Do'h!!. I see what you mean. sorry they wanted to be able to click anycell in the row and not use the selector.
:'(.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have found my answer, for anyone else who might need the same thing. check this out.
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=8279

My required was to be able to de-select as-well 
add this code to remove highlight

row.Selected = false;                    this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.ActiveRowAppearance.Reset();